# Regular Expression to Parse Custom Email Address

Tags: php, regex, email

I need to parse email custom email addresses that will all fit a similar format to this:

```
custom.name+1234@my.custom.domain
```

I need a regex that will capture everything before the plus (+) sign, the number after the plus sign and what comes after the @ symbol. It is possible for an email to come through that doesn't have the plus (+) sign as well.

My first, basic attempt looks like this but is obviously wrong somehow:

```
preg_match('#([A-Za-z0-9._])+([\d])@(.*)#', 'customemail+123@domain.com', $matches);
```

Comment: Can't you `explode()` it twice, once on `@` and then on `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that square brackets indicate a single character.

If you want to allow more than one of those things, you need a quantifier, like * for zero or more, or + for 1 or more.

You'll need to escape the plus symbol, as it's used for the purpose I already described. Also we'd need to mark that as optional using a ? quantifier (means zero or one).

So we'd end up with something like:

`'#([A-Za-z0-9._]+)\+?([\d]*)@(.*)#'`

Hope that helps

Comment: I think the OP means `(?:\+\d+)?` i.e. the group "plus and digits" as a whole is optional before `@`.

Comment: Also, you might want to be slightly stricter about what you allow after `@`, depending of course on where the input is coming from (if you know from the context that it must be a valid email address, you can be less strict).

Answer (score 0):

I use this regular expression:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/'
```

but if is compatible only with tld in length of 2-4 charactes. So it is not compatible with new tlds like ".company" ... So if you want to be compatible with longer tlds, just change {2,4} to {2,10} for maximal length of 10 characters (just use length of longest tld you want).

Comment: This will match `++++++@..com`, not sure that is wanted. And doesn't match tld like `museum` or `travel`.

Comment: You are right that domain ..com is not good. However ++++++@a.a.com is valid so it should be wanted to. I changed my regexp and I add some more of my knowledge about RFC norm in e-mail. For example underscore "_" can't be in domain name, but can be in DNS name (before domain name - example ++@_host._name.domain.com is valid). I added longer gtld too. So now it is more accurate `#^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)$#i`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
([\w.]+)(?:\+(\d+))?@(.*)
```

group 1 will contain the name
group 2 will contain the number after the + sign 
group 3 will contain the domain.